# Push.io can't send notification to a single device from dashboard

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Push.io can't send notification to a single device from their dashboard.

When I tried to send a message using its UUID it showed that the message was sent, but the device didn't receive any message.

NSString *uuid = [[PushIOManager sharedInstance] pushIOUUID];

I am using this "uuid" based on Push.io documentation. Also let me know if anyone aware of the correct query to target push messages using this 'uuid' from push.io dashboard.

Currently using a trial account to verify the behavior of Push.io.

Comment: So it's working for other devices?

Comment: @shim When i broadcast to all devices without any filtration it works, all devices get a push notification. but when i try to only send to a specific device doesn't happen!

Comment: Where are you getting the UUID from ?

Comment: NSString *uuid = [[PushIOManager sharedInstance] pushIOUUID];


I am using this "uuid" based on Push.io documentation.

Also let me know if you are aware of the correct query when targeting push messages from push.io dashboard.

Comment: Add what you're using now to your question
Do trial accounts have access to all features? Have you tried contacting their support directly?

Comment: Their customer support is the worst!! no response for more than one week!